# Fetch windows setting value

Tags: winapi, windows-8, winjs

How do I fetch the `Measurement System` setting value in javascript?

I'm guessing that it would be throw some WinJS call.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical place would be [Windows.Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.aspx), but not seeing if offered there. One pretty simple workaround - faster to write than to research the setting :) is to create a Windows Runtime Component in C# that calls in to [System.Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx):

```
namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent
{
    public sealed class RegionalSettings
    {
        public bool isMetric()
        {
            return System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add as a reference to your JavaScript app and invoke there:

```
var r = new WindowsRuntimeComponent.RegionalSettings;
var isMetric = r.isMetric();
```

Comment: Would this reflect the user settings? Say default setting for my locale is metric, but I manually change it to US (through the settings dialog), will I get the default value or the value I set?

Comment: @Aki it will give you the current value of the setting.

Comment: Tried it .. it does indeed pick he value from the user settings! Thanks :)